# Tool / apis similar to ddms for integration with android app

Tags: android, ddms

As I am new to android, this question might seems very basic to some people. We are creating an android app and want to monitor it after release in a similar manner as [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) does for local debugging. Is their anything available in that space ?

-
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can still start ddms by command line.
Go to your terimal(command line), move to sdk folder 
then type command: `tools/ddms`
It'll start a stand alone ddms version.

Comment: Our usecase is, after release , we want to know how well app is performing (cpu usage, network rx and tx and battery consumption). How can we monitor that ?

Comment: @nishantpathak You can implement some analyst sdk like GoogleAnalystics, Crashlytics, Flurry ..., they provide method to log back device's status.